# How to share AWS infrastructure among multiple accounts using Terraform and AWS SSO?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I have the following multi-account setup with AWS SSO:

- An account called "infrastructure-owner". Under this account, there is a role called "SomeAccessLevel" where I can click to sign-in the web console.
- Another account called "infrastructure-consumer". Under this account there is the same role called "SomeAccessLevel" where I can click to sign-in the web console. There may be other roles.

Account "infrastructure-owner" owns resources (for example S3 buckets, DynamoDB tables, or VPNs) typically with read/write access. This account is somewhat protected and rarely used. Account "infrastructure-consumer" merely have read access to resources in "infrastructure-owner". This account is used often by multiple people/services. For example, production data pipelines run in "infrastructure-consumer" and have read-only rights to S3 buckets in "infrastructure-owner". However, from time to time, new data may be included manually in these S3 buckets via sign-in "infrastructure-owner".

**I would like to provision this infrastructure with Terraform. I am unable to provide permissions for "infrastructure-consumer" to access resources from "infrastructure-owner".** I've read dozens of blog posts on AWS multi-account / SSO / Terraform but I still cannot do it. At this point, I cannot even do it manually in the web console.

Please realize that "SomeAccessLevel" is a **role created by AWS that I cannot modify** (typically called AWSReservedSSO_YOURNAMEHERE_RANDOMSTRING). Also, **I cannot give permissions to particular users**, since these users may not be owned by "infrastructure-consumer". Also, users access this account via SSO using a role.

The following Terraform code is an example DynamoDB table created in the "infrastructure-owner" that I would like to read in the "infrastructure-consumer" account (any role):

```
# Terraform config
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.44"
    }
  }

  backend "remote" {
    hostname = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "YOUR_ORGANIZATION_HERE"

    workspaces {
      name = "YOUR_TF_WORKSPACE_NAME_HERE"  # linked to "infrastructure-owner" 
    }
  }
}

# Local provider
provider "aws" {
  profile = "YOUR_AWS_PROFILE_NAME_HERE"  # linked to "infrastructure-owner" 
  region = "eu-central-1"
}

# Example resource that I would like to access from other accounts like "infrastructure-consumer"
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "my-database" {

  # Basic
  name           = "my-database"
  billing_mode   = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key       = "uuid"

  # Key
  attribute {
    name = "uuid"
    type = "S"
  }
}

# YOUR CODE TO ALLOW "infrastructure-consumer" TO READ THE TABLE.
```

It could also happen that there is a better architecture for this use case. I am trying to follow general practices for AWS multi-account for production environments, and Terraform for provisioning them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean AWS accounts and not IAM accounts (users).

I remember that roles to be assumed via AWS SSO had something called permission sets, which is no more than a policy with API actions allowed|denied to be performed while assuming a role. I don't know exactly how AWS SSO could influence how role trust works in AWS, but you could have a role in **infrastructure-owner's account** that trusts anything in **infrastructure-consumer's account**, i.e. trusting `"arn:aws:iam::${var.infrastructure-consumer's account}:root"`

To achieve that with Terraform you would run it in your management account (SSO Administrator's Account) and make that trust happen.